# How to get mucroom offline messages

Tags: xmpp, strophe

How to retrieve mucroom offline messages from openfire and any plugin available for this one?

Thank you,

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you provide your code? What have you tried so far, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: How to get group messages while group member comes to online by using open fire.

For example:
In a group there are 5 members, When Member1 sents message to his group out of 4, 3 receives his message while they are in online, 1 does't gets any message bcoz he is in offline, My question is while he comes online how to get group message by using open fire.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Multi User Chat in XMPP is presence based. When you are online you get the message. When you get offline, you leave the room and will not get anymore message until you join the room again by sending a presence message.

Update: With ejabberd 16.09, you can now use MUC/Sub protocol to subscribe to chat rooms. When subscribed, you do not have to join the room again to receive the messages. Protocol is documented here: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/